# VS Code recognized the import but still shows ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently developing some packages with multiple subfolders. However, when I try to import one function from a subfolder into another one, the VS code shows green but when I run it, the terminal says ModuleNotFoundError. The folder structure is shown below.

```
Folder
|-Subfolder_1
|-- __init__.py
|-- fitting.py
|- Subfolder_2
|-- __init__.py
|-- process.py
|- main.py
```

When I import subfolder_1 to main.py, it works fine, but when I try to import fitting.py to process.py, the problem occurs. I tried to mess around with the settings in vscode but nothing worked. I also tried to just put them in the same subfolder, but when I do that, the process.py functions properly but main.py throws an error for modules not found since I use process.py in the main.py.

If anyone has some idea of how to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:
Tried the sys.path.append for importing and the same error occurred.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path/to/file/subfolder_2/process.py", line 6, in <module>
    import  fitting 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fitting'
```

EDIT 2: When I move fitting.py into the same subfolder with process.py and import fitting, the code runs and behave properly (folder structure after the traceback message). However, when I call functions in process.py in main.py by import, this error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from subfolder_1 import process
  File "/path/to/subfolder_1/process.py", line 4, in <module>
    import Fitting
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Fitting'
```

```
Folder
|- Subfolder_1
|-- __init__.py
|-- process.py
|-- fitting.py
|- main.py
```

EDIT 3: I am currently working with a workaround for this by having fitting.py and process.py in the same subfolder but not calling process.py within main.py and have another file for the functions used for main.py; however, I would like to know why is this error occurring and what can fit it since it would be great for future reference if I have to revert back to the old structure.

Comment: How are you running `main.py`? And please include the whole [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples) in your question body.

Comment: I am running the main.py in vs code with if __name__ == '__main__': within the venv for python 3.8.1. Also added the traceback message to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `virtual environment` then you need activate it.

for **Mac OS / Linux**

`source <path to env>/bin/activate`

for **Windows**

`<path to env>\Scripts\activate`

Comment: Yes I am using a venv and I did activated it prior for most of the development process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a path. However, it should be noted that vscode searches for files with the workspace as the root directory.

Here I assume that you have a workspace that contains your directory structure.

You can try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".\Folder\Subfolder_1")
import fitting
```

Example:
Here **`my_python`** is my workspace. And it involves a project named **`mainfloder`** like your `**Floder**`.

[image]

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".\mainfloder\projectfloder\pages")
from webpages import SignUpPage

print(SignUpPage())
```

I can get it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the sys.path.append to the fitting folder and import from there but the same module not found error occurred when I tried to import fitting.

Comment: @Sean Hu Have you checked the project and the workspace? As I said, Vscode takes the workspace as the root directory, and you need to adjust it according to your settings.

Comment: thank you fro the reply. I recently switched to Vscode and I was checking the setting.json but I don't see a workspace setting contained within. My folder structure within the Vscode is basically the "projectfolder" structure you shown here, so I assume the workspace would be "projectfolder" in my case here? so the sys.path.append would have arg (".\projectfolder\pages") if I understand it correctly.

Comment: I think you can try both ways "(".\projectfolder\pages")" and "(".\pages")" if you like. Because "." means the current floder instead of parent directory.